# Design for a component with 2 listeners and 2 "setters" (Swing application)

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, listener

I'm making a map editor using java swing for my tile based java game. the swing application has two major components, the "upper" component is the game map preview, and the "lower" component is modifyable properties of the map, like its height and width.

Currently the user types in to a jtextfield for the map width, then I use a change listener to set that value to the GameMap object. The GameMap object when changed fires a notification event to GameMapListeners, the primary listener it has is the preview display of the map inside the swing application.

This lets the user change the map width and instnatly see the results in a preview pane.

Now I want to go to the other way. I want the user to be able to click and drag the edges of the map  in the preview pane, but then the results need to then be sent to the properties panel so it shows the updated width value.

This is where the problem is, if I update the jtextfield it'll fire a change event, which would update the GameMap and update the preview display, and then that would fire an event that changes the jtextfield again (so on and on until the program crashes due to stack overflow)

Are there any kind of design patterns i could use instead, or is there some common way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In this type of case, you have at least two choices...

### You Could

Remove the listener to the other component when you want to trigger a change, adding it back after you've raised the event...

### You Could

Change the state of a flag to indicate that you should ignore any changes that might come in, resetting after you're raised the event...

Which one you choose will depend on how much code you want to add and how readily available the reference to the listeners in question are (ie, if you don't have a reference to the listener you want to remove, it's kind of hard to implement)

Answer (score 1):

> If I update the jtextfield it'll fire a change event, which would update the GameMap and update the preview display, and then that would fire an event that changes the jtextfield again (so on and on until the program crashes due to stack overflow).

When you have a situation like this, you can temporarily remove event listeners, fire the change event, and add the event listeners back.  Yes, this is as much of a pain as it sounds, but it's a good way to prevent the stack overflow.

You can see a detailed explanation as well as a working example of managing event listeners in my [Sudoku Solver Swing GUI](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=196) article.

Answer (score 0):

You can use action events for a JTextField. Action events don't trigger when you change the component programmatically.

Comment: I'm using the value changed listener to listen for updates to the jtextfield (the jtextfield holds numbers, and the mousehweel lets you scroll up/down through the numbers, the value listener is the only way i could find to reliablly "hear" all changes to the text field and pass them on to the GameMap

Comment: You can use a document listener to hear all changes to the text although that may also trigger the event. Otherwise I recommend what MadProgrammer says. I use a flag when I absolutely have to use a change listener.